# Date not valid for month specified - ORA-01839

Tags: sql, oracle, function

Is it possible inside function put execption to avoid a mistake if put wrong date?

```
Select F_RETURN_DAY_NAME(2021,6,30) from dual;     --WORK (Jun have 30 days)
Select F_RETURN_DAY_NAME(2021,6,31) from dual;     --DONT WORK



create or replace Function F_RETURN_DAY_NAME
       ( 
         p_year IN number,
         p_month IN number,
         p_day IN number
       )
       RETURN varchar2
    IS
       v_return varchar2(100);
    
    BEGIN
    
         return substr(to_char(TO_DATE(p_year || '-' || p_month || '-' || p_day, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'DY'),0,3) ; 
    
    END;
```

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? (Query v$version if not sure). OK, you updated the question already, to change from wanting a default value to an exception; but it's already throwing an exception - so what do you want to happen instead?

Comment: It is possible, either (as Alex Poole will suggest, if your Oracle version is high enough) by using the default on conversion error option to `to_date`, or if your version is older, you can do the calculation in a nested block and capture and handle the error there - then after the error is handled, control returns to the main block.

Comment: @AlexPoole  Version 19,  if don't have resaults return eg, "Wrong day" in v_return

Comment: @mathguy  I don't know is it possible solve this problem with  some simple solution, I have 3 parameter and need get first 3 character from day name.

Comment: Of course *you* don't know if it's possible, that is why you asked the question here. Alex has already shown you one easy way. Now, further question for you: What if the month, for example, is wrong? Like 14 for the month? Alex's solution will still report `'Wrong day'`, when in fact what is wrong is the month. Is that a problem?

Comment: @mathguy  I will put universal error message eg. Error  for both month and day, tnx for suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're on a recent version you can use the `default ... on conversion error` [clause for `to_date()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html#GUID-D226FA7C-F7AD-41A0-BB1D-BD8EF9440118):

```
create or replace Function F_RETURN_DAY_NAME
( 
  p_year IN number,
  p_month IN number,
  p_day IN number
)
  RETURN varchar2
IS
BEGIN
  return coalesce(
    to_char(to_date(p_year || '-' || p_month || '-' || p_day
      default null on conversion error, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'DY'),
    'Wrong day') ; 
END;
/
```

which gets:

```
Select F_RETURN_DAY_NAME(2021,6,30) from dual;

F_RETURN_DAY_NAME(2021,6,30)
----------------------------
WED
```

and

```
Select F_RETURN_DAY_NAME(2021,6,31) from dual;

F_RETURN_DAY_NAME(2021,6,31)
----------------------------
Wrong day
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=eac56e2fdeec2dc1a429f5cef5f275de)

I've removed the local variable you weren't using; and the substring - DY gives you the abbreviated day name. In English that's always three characters anyway; in other languages it can be longer, but as that's to avoid ambiguity only taking the first three characters is going to cause confusion. If you want to ensure the day abbreviation is always a specific language, regardless of the user's session settings, then you can supply another argument to `to_char()`:

```
  return coalesce(
    to_char(to_date(p_year || '-' || p_month || '-' || p_day
      default null on conversion error, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
      'DY',
      'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'),
    'Wrong day') ;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b9e190db58e514fb2989d3d2a0caf9bb)

---

> The concern is that the function may also be called on null input, which is not invalid; the function should indeed return null in that case (guessing here, but that is what most use cases would require, I think), rather than returning 'Wrong day'

You can check for all values being null before attempting conversion:

```
...
  if p_year is null and p_month is null and p_day is null then
    return null;
  end if;

  return coalesce(
...
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1f0e5faf92b8b0307c44f8e56e92a843)

You'll need to decide how you want to handle only one or two arguments being null; at the moment that (or month 13, or year 10000) will all return 'Wrong day'. If you want any null argument to return null then do the same thing but with 'or' instead of 'and', for example. And you might want a more generic return value on error - 'Invalid date', say, which I've used in the latest Fiddle.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use some fictitious date as default, and use a slightly more complicated `case` expression to return `'Wrong day'`? The concern is that the function may also be called on `null` input, which is not invalid; the function should indeed return `null` in that case (guessing here, but that is what most use cases would require, I think), rather than returning `'Wrong day'`.

Comment: Maybe, but then you're using a magic value, which isn't great either. If it's valid to have all null components then can check for that before attempting conversion.

Comment: Indeed - best to check for null first. In any case, I realized there are other potential problems - I just asked the OP what should happen if, for example, the wrong month was provided, not the wrong day-of-the-month. Then probably handling in a nested block would be more convenient, even with default on error available in newer versions.